# Query with date period and more

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table named table1:

```
id  name    event    date
1   name1   f        2010-02-26 21:49:46
2   name2   f        2011-01-21 14:30:26
3   name3   f        2010-05-25 20:51:07
4   name2   r        2011-03-21 21:49:46
5   name4   t        2011-09-15 21:30:26
6   name2   t        2010-01-20 13:07:55
7   name2   t        2011-02-24 20:51:09
8   name1   r        2011-05-20 16:07:55
9   name2   r        2009-07-23 07:51:11
10  name2   r        2011-09-20 21:49:46
```

A) So I want the result to be in 4 columns:

```
name    f   r   t
name1   f:1 r:1 t:0
name2   f:1 r:3 t:2
```

B) moreover I want to be order in relation with the bigest sum of f*2, r*0.5, t*4 DESC:

C) moreover I want to count the number of events only in a specific period for example last week, month, last 6 months. Can you embeded the below SQL query to yor answer? Are there more types of intervals like months years or hours?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a few self joins (Note:  This is untested, since I don't have an installation of MySQL hanging around, but this should work).

```
select a.name, f,r,t
from(
    select name, count(1) as f,2*count(1) as f_sum
    from table1
    where date >=current_date-30 --or whatever date range you want
    and event='f'
    group by name
    )a
join(
    select name, ,count(1) as r,0.5*count(1) as r_sum
    from table1
    where date >=current_date-30 --or whatever date range you want
    and event='r'
    group by name
    )b
on a.name=b.name
join(
    select name, count(1) as t,4*count(1) as t_sum
    from table1
    where date >=current_date-30 --or whatever date range you want
    and event='t'
    group by name
    )c
on b.name=c.name
order by f_sum+r_sum+t_sum desc;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'text) as f,2*count(1) as f_sum from table1 where date >=current_date-30 ' at line 3

Comment: Oops, I goofed with the syntax for `cast()`.  I've made an edit.

Comment: sorry another one: #1052 - Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Weird...that shouldn't happen since I'm making all of the joins using `name`.  No matter, I've made an edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1.One last thing maybe the "cast(count(1) as text)" has to change to "cast(count(*) as unsigned integer)". 2.All I get are "1" in every column and row.

Comment: Sorry, I should've checked up on whether or not MySQL lets you concatenate a string with an integer (apparently, you can).  Edit made.

Comment: I make this change: SELECT name, COUNT( 1 ) AS r, 0.5 * COUNT( 1 ) AS r_sum. and then it works

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought you needed the string literal `"r:"` in front of the count.  I'm glad I was able to help.  :)